# Panel/Pop Up Notification issues after upgrading to Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, notification, panel, 19.04

A little help please!

I just upgraded to Kubuntu 19.04 and am experiencing a little, albeit annoying, issue.

2 issues, actually.

**1.** When I first log in and am presented with the Kubuntu desktop I have to do a little adjusting to the panel (I have my desktop layed out with a panel at the top and Latte Dock at the bottom ala MacOS). The top panel appears 1/3 of the way down on the desktop. I have to right-click the panel to access the preferences and then move it back into position at the top of the screen. This happens everytime I login.

**2.** Pop up notifications are HUGE. And I mean they take up the whole screen. Whenever a song changes..BOOM! The whole screen is a notification that interrupts workflow. Very annoying! Even when adjusting the system volume on the panel using my mouse wheel the volume bar notification pop up takes up the entire screen. It used to be a nice small pop up in the middle of the screen as were all other notifications.

*******I must note that at times the pop ups do not take up the whole screen but rather appear 1/3 of the way down and span the width of the screen...about the same size as the Panel when I 1st login.

I can't figure this out folks. I tried the Notification setting but nothing there as to size. At first I thought it might be an Accessibility setting but nothing there either. I am suspecting an issue with the Panel itself..although I have looked at the Panel Settings and have not found anything that could be the source.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Create a second user account and see if these phenomena persist. If the other user is normal, some config in your first user is corrupt and you'll need to figure that out.

Comment: Hmm...good idea. I'll shall try that.

Comment: Yep..did as you suggested and indeed the user acct is normal. I am suspecting that it may be the panel itself. I can't figure it out still. Is there a way to re-install the Panel or reset it to its defaults?

Comment: Elsewhere you've mentioned booting into Xubuntu. Do you have both Xubuntu and Kubuntu on the same system where you can choose between them at login or do you choose between them from the GRUB screen?

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove the panel and add a new one. Did you try it?

To remove the panel you just have to right click it, choose "Edit Panel" and finally "Remove Panel".

To add a new one you just have to right click anywhere in your desktop, put the mouse over "Add panel" and then choose the panel template you want to add.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Although this answer may be helpful even in its current state, I recommend that you **[edit]** it to describe *how* to do this.